Issues downloading data using CopernicusMarine R package
Not quite sure what's going on here. I'm simply trying to run one of the examples here but nothing is happening. My credentials are registered, which I tested using cms_list_stac_files() and cms_download_stac(), but when I run cms_download_subset() It seems to run but nothing happens (no messages or errors).
library(CopernicusMarine)

cms_login(
username = getOption("CopernicusMarine_uid", "username"),
password = getOption("CopernicusMarine_pwd", "password"))

destination <- tempfile("copernicus", fileext = ".nc")

cms_download_subset(
  destination   = destination,
  product       = "GLOBAL_ANALYSISFORECAST_PHY_001_024",
  layer         = "cmems_mod_glo_phy-cur_anfc_0.083deg_P1D-m",
  variable      = "sea_water_velocity",
  region        = c(-1, 50, 10, 55),
  timerange     = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02"),
  verticalrange = c(0, -2))




Copernicus is in the middle of a complete restructuring of their data distribution services. Since they are still migrating, a bunch of data is simply not available. Additionally, without major restructuring, a package written around the historic data distribution methods will be unable to access data. ESA/Copernicus have also moved to a token based EU wide credentials system.

Looks like there's an issue in the tracker for this package, so follow along at https://github.com/pepijn-devries/CopernicusMarine/issues/42 - if that's not your problem then open a new issue, but I suspect its related to the restructuring.

Ok thanks @JeffreyEvans and @Spacedman that helps a lot. You are both right. For anyone else, the interim solution is to use cms_download_stac() to get the entire dataset and subset manually
